# What is the meaning of "plumbing"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I ran into the following sentence from this [article](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/comparing-swarm-swarmkit-and-swarm-mode/):

> ...“Swarmkit” to refer to the plumbing open source orchestration project.

After referring [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plumbing), I still can't figure out what is the exact meaning of *plumbing* here. Could anyone help to explain it?

Comment: The article has a link to that very question https://www.londonrents.work/what-is-the-meaning-of-plumbing/ it seems to be a specific usage in the Docker world for infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referring to an open source project called plumbing. It likely got its name from the common usage of plumbing to mean 'inner workings', like the plumbing in the walls, it's there, and you don't typically see it, but it's just back there working.

Comment: No, the project is not called "plumbing".

Comment: So the plumbing open source orchestration project isn't what they were referring to?

Comment: It is what they are referring to. If this answer replaced the word *named* by eg *regarding* or *providing*, it would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Plumbing** is being used simply as an **adjective** to describe a project  involving reusable software components.

Quoting a [tweet](https://twitter.com/solomonstre/status/740371317958934528) from Solomon Hykes the founder of Docker :

> More open-source plumbing fom Docker: SwarmKit is a **toolkit to orchestrate distributed systems at any scale.**

Quoting [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11859615) :

> SwarmKit [...]
>    **small individual components (the "plumbing")** which other products can use and contribute back to  [...]